# About $C([-1,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Define the space $C([-1,1])$ as the space of continuous functions $f : [-1,1] \mapsto \Bbb R$ with   metric $$ d(f,g) = \sup _{x \in [-1,1]}{|f(x)-g(x)|} ,  $$

Now which of following options is **NOT** closed set in $C([-1,1])$ ?

1- the set of all continuous functions such that $f(0)=0$ .

2.the set of all integrable functions $f$  such that $ \int_{-1}^{1} f(x)  dx =0$

3-the set of all continuous and even functions such that $f(0)=0$ .

4-the set of all differentiable functions such that $ f^{'}(0)=0$.

I think "2 " is closed set because The integral function is a linear application and a member of the dual of the space $C([-1,1])$ so we have that

$A=(\int_{-1}^1dx)^{-1}(\{0\})$

that it is closed because it is the inverse image of a closed set with respect to a continuous function.

Comment: (1) The functional $\phi(f)=f(0)$ is continuous because $|\phi(f)-\phi(g)|\leq \|f-g\|$. The set in question is $\phi^{-1}(\{0\})$. (2) Consider $\phi(f)=\int_{[-1,1]} f$. You have that $|\phi(f)-\phi(g)|\leq 2\|f-g\|$. The set in question is $\phi^{-1}(\{0\})$. (3) is the intersection of (1) and $A=\{f: f(x)=f(-x)\}$. Consider $\phi(f)(x)=f(-x)$. This satisfies $\|\phi(f)-\phi(g)\|\leq\|f-g\|$. So, $\phi$ is continuous and $A=(\phi-I)^{-1}(\{0\})$.

Comment: For (4) just take differentiable function that are zero on $[-1,1/2]$ and that converge uniformly to $f(x)=x-1/2$ for $x\geq1/2$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x<1/2$.

Comment: @Boxwood .so (4) is not close set ?

Comment: Yes, it is not closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate for "2" ... prove this:

> If $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ and $\int_{-1}^1 f_n(x)\,dx = 0$ for all $n$, then $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,dx = 0$.

This shows the set is closed.

Do the others in the same way:  your metric corresponds to uniform convergence.  These facts should be more elementary than anything about "dual space", so I would avoid mention of that.